# Why is std::is_error_code_enum<std::errc>::value false?

Tags: c++, c++11, error-code

[`std::is_error_code_enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code/is_error_code_enum) is described as:

> If T is an error code enumeration, this template provides the member constant value equal true.

[`std::errc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc) is described as:

> The scoped enumeration std::errc defines the values of portable error conditions

Surely then, `std::is_error_code_enum<std::errc>::value` should be `true`? Yet for me, it's false. Is this deliberate?

---

This matters, because without it, the implicit conversion from `std::errc` to  `std::error_code` does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::errc` is an enum of error *conditions*.  That means

```
std::is_error_condition_enum<T>::value;
```

will be `true`.  Since it is not a enum of error *codes*

```
std::is_error_code_enum<T>::value;
```

should be, and is, `false`.

Comment: Very confusing how `std::errc` is an error condition but `std::io_errc` is an error code

Comment: @Eric Yeah, the naming isn't the greatest.

Comment: I'm not sure I like this answer. Take the description of `std::error_code`'s 3rd constructor: "Constructs error code from an error code enum e. Equivalent to `*this = make_error_code(e)`. The overload participates in overload resolutions only if `std::is_error_code_enum<ErrorCodeEnum>::value == true`." This implies to me that `std::is_error_code_enum<T>::value == true` indicates the existence of `make_error_code(T)`, and [there is a `std::make_error_code(std::errc)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc/make_error_code).

Comment: They could have just named it 'error_cond' to match 'error_code'

Answer (score 1):

[[system_error.syn]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/system_error.syn#1):

> The is_­error_­code_­enum and is_­error_­condition_­enum may be
>   specialized for program-defined types to indicate that such types are
>   eligible for class error_­code and class error_­condition automatic
>   conversions, respectively.

is_error_condition_enum<>::value value is `true` for `std::errc`:

```
template<> struct is_error_condition_enum<errc> : true_type {};
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to enable `std::error_code` constructor and assignment operator from `std::errc` we need to explicitly say that `std::is_error_code_enum<std::errc>` should return true. Otherwise the constructor and assignment operator will be disabled.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>

// Enable error_code(errc) and error_code = errc
template <> struct std::is_error_code_enum<std::errc>
    : std::true_type {};

int main() {
    std::error_code inv_arg1(std::errc::invalid_argument);
    std::error_code inv_arg2;
    inv_arg2 = std::errc::invalid_argument;
    std::cout << inv_arg1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << inv_arg2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

More details [system_error header](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/system_error#L330)

Comment: While this will indeed work, I suspect specializing stdlib templates with stdlib types is "allowed" by the standard, making this a bad idea.